# 3.5 inch HDD making clicking noise (video included)

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, sata, hard-drive-recovery

Seeking Advice: Recovering Data from Clicking 3.5" HDD

I have an approximately 10-year-old 3.5-inch SATA hard drive that I'm trying to get old personal files off of. When connected via a SATA-to-USB enclosure or cable, the drive starts emitting a repeating clicking sound and is not detected by my computer (running Windows 10).

After observing the behaviour, I opened the enclosure in a dust-free environment to visually inspect the drive. The actuator arm seems to move back and forth randomly for a few seconds before the clicking resumes. I captured this on video linked below:

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqLAp1ucNteiiax_4tpAAKcCnCuEHg

It seems like some mechanical failure - possibly a dead motor or heads. I have basic electronics skills but limited experience with hard drive repairs.

Before considering a full-blown professional recovery service, I wanted to check if the community might recommend any other DIY troubleshooting steps I should try first. The main goal is to access the drive enough to copy key personal files off it.

If a physical repair is unrealistic without clean room tools, at what point is a professional platter data recovery service advisable, considering the costs? Any reputable providers you recommend using as a last resort?

Appreciate any insights or suggested next steps!

Comment: Though you "opened the enclosure in a dust-free environment," that likely decreased the chances of recovering anything. At this point, the only feasible option is commercial data recovery, costly, and without guarantee. BTW, on a drive that was balky, but *was* recognized, I found chilling gave a few minutes of readability.

Comment: place the drive into a freezer overnight ... try to read data as soon as you take it out ... the cold sometimes tightens up worn parts long enough to get data

Comment: I find it improbable you "opened the enclosure in a dust-free environment" - unless you have an industrial clean room facility, you introduced dust when opening the drive

Comment: Sorry, but the drive is definitely dead the moment you opened it. I concur with @warren that I doubt you truly had a “dust free environment” to open it in. You perhaps had a very superficially clean work table, but not enough to ensure dust particles did not rush in and rest on the platters. It only takes seconds for that to happen. The drive is now dead; a paperweight at best.

Comment: @jsotola That old advice is fairly useless. Especially if the case was opened. Might as well light a candle, kill a few chickens in sacrifice and pray if you believe that freezing nonsense on modern (post-1993) drives.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I recovered data from a failing drive that way about 6 years ago ... I do not know the year of manufacture of that drive though ... so it may be worth a try

Answer (score 3):

It appears the drive can not read the SA (service area). It's very simple: the question is, what's the data worth? If say > $400 then stop experimenting.

1. Even labs with 'certified' clean rooms and cabinets don't run the drive without lid off. They inspect, diagnose, repair and clean it, put the lid back and then run the drive.
2. A lab doesn't need lookie-lookie like you did, they can tell by listening that heads move, try to read SA and fail at doing so. By hooking the drive up to diagnostic hardware they may already be be to tell which of the heads doesn't play nice for example or that the clicking is simply result of firmware issues for example. Some times a lab knowns, based on experience, clicking + drive model + not dropped = 90% probable firmware issue.
3. Anything you do will only make things worse and more expensive if you decide at some point to send the drive to a data recovery lab. It has already become more expensive because a lab will be able to tell the drive was opened, and 9 out 10 labs will charge extra for previously opened drive. For example $300 data recovery website states: "For drives with previously opened covers, we charge an up-front/non-refundable $100 'open cover' fee."